# How to add Application Insights in Azure Bot Service

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-bot-service

I created one **Basic Bot** in **Azure Bot Service** and also configured **Continuous Integration** to that bot, I want to add **Application Insights** to that Azure Bot Service, is it possible or not?

Thanks,
Sai Priya. C

Answer (score 0):

Don't see why not.
Basically you right-click on the Project (not the Solution), and select Add Application Insights Telemetry from the pop-up menu, and continue with the wizard as you would with any application.

[This](https://web.archive.org/web/20170615212911/http://aihelpwebsite.com/Blog/EntryId/11/Using-Application-Insights-With-Microsoft-Bot-Framework) seems like a good reference for detailed process.
(Original link is effectively 404; link redirected to archive.org)